# defined a local function for a partition in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I am trying to learn Spark using Python (Pyspark). I want to run a local algorithm for data points which is partitioned.  For more clarity, i have some data points and transformed into  pair:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/lixru3v51509045359106/new__1-c5826.txt"); 
result = rdd.map(lambda x: (x.split(',')[0], x.split(',')[1:])).partitionBy(2).persist();
```

print result.glom().collect()[1];

```
[[(u'1', [u'1', u'1']), (u'2', [u'1', u'2']), (u'3', [u'3', u'4']), (u'4', [u'5', u'7'])], [(u'5', [u'3', u'5']), (u'6', [u'4', u'5']), (u'7', [u'3', u'4'])]]
```

and two partitioned into two section.

```
[[(u'1', [u'1', u'1']), (u'3', [u'3', u'4']), (u'5', [u'3', u'5']), (u'7', [u'3', u'4'])], [(u'2', [u'1', u'2']), (u'4', [u'5', u'7']), (u'6', [u'4', u'5'])]]
```

Now i am going run a local algorithm for labeling each data points in each partition.for example for partition 1 i am going to run local clustering algorithm.

```
[(u'2', [u'1', u'2']), (u'4', [u'5', u'7']), (u'6', [u'4', u'5'])]
```

How to write  function for each partition?

Comment: How does your current code looks like? How far did you get? Where do you exactly need help?

Comment: rdd = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/lixru3v51509045359106/new__1-c5826.txt"); 
result = rdd.map(lambda x: (x.split(',')[0], x.split(',')1:])).partitionBy(2).persist(); i am going to run a function for each partition.I think i should use mapPartitions() for each map but i don't know how how?

Comment: A better place for you code would be your question, use the edit-button to include your code and do not forget to describe what the code already does.